# React Redux export default with 2 functions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm very new to React so please forgive me if this is a stupid question but I'm stuck on the following:

Currently I have this:

```js
export default connect()(PrechatForm);
```

Now I want to translate some text of the text inside the render function with react-i18next. Their guides say I have to do something like this:

```js
export default translate()(PrechatForm);
```

But since the connect function is already there I'm not sure how to combine these to. In the end I guess it should look something like this: (which isn't valid JS of course)

```js
export default connect(PrechatForm)()translate()(PrechatForm);
```

The whole example looks like this:

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { translate } from 'react-i18next';

class PrechatForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
  const { t } = this.props;
    return (
      {t.('translateme')}
    );
  }
}

export default connect()(PrechatForm);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Straight forward solution is to use

```
export default translate()(connect()(PrechatForm));
```

I.e. first connecting to Redux and then translating the connected component.

EDIT: To help visualise you can see it like this

```
const connector = connect();
const translator = translate();

export default translator(connector(PrechatForm));
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that makes it clear whats happening!